# Update Django session variable in javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, session

I want to update a Django session variable following a Javascript event (well, actually jQuery).

Do I need to do this via a POST request?

Or can Javascript and Django share session variables in some clever way, in which case can I update the session variables direct from jQuery? I'm a bit hazy on the details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do this via Ajax. You'll need a simple Django view that updates the session variable, which the jQuery will call:

```
def update_session(request):
    if not request.is_ajax() or not request.method=='POST':
        return HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST'])

    request.session['mykey'] = 'myvalue'
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

and the JS:

```
$.post('/update_session/', function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Comment: You have a typo in your Django view, a trailing `]` after you assign the value. Also, you should return `HttpResponseNotAllowed(['POST',])` instead of `Http404()`

Comment: Hope you don't mind my fix. Also replaced `and not` by `or not`.

Comment: How, can we make it more generalized that, you can set any p

Comment: Is it secure to get mykey and myvalue from request parameters?

Comment: @porton why  not?

Comment: @enesislam They are visible in the URL.

Comment: @porton No they are not if you use post request as you can see on the above answer.